# Conditional Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, forms, select, html-select

I need to build a conditional set of select menus using JavaScript or a JS library without using a database because it's only for a simple prototype. However, I'm a beginner at JS and haven't been able to find a solution.

You can see a non-functioning visual reference here:

http://jsfiddle.net/js_noob/n3Fwg/

Stack Overflow requires me to post code from JSFiddle:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Two Part Select</title>
<style>
    p, select {
    float: left;
}
br {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
}
form {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p style="margin-left: 20px;">A</p>
<p style="margin-left: 50px;">B</p>
<br>
<form>

<select style="float: left;">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
</select>


<select style="float: left; margin-left: 20px;">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
</select>

<button style="float: left; margin-left: 20px;">Submit</button>

</form>

<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's a description of the required functionality:

Select Menu A has numbers from 1 to 13 as does Menu B. They are not chained but there is a conditional aspect required of them. For example, say in Menu A you select "5" and in Menu B you select "7", on submit I need to pull a file that is unique to that particular combination, let's call it "57.html" as an example. Or, if in Menu A "4" is chosen and in Menu B "8" is selected, it would pull a file called "48.html" on submit.

All the online demos of two select menus working together that I've found seem to have chained menus where the second menu is populated *after* selecting something in the first, and that's **not** what I want. For example:

http://javascript.about.com/library/bldydrop1.htm

In my case, the two have to work together but Menu B's numbers must always be visible and will reference the numerical selection in Menu A to call the proper file.

Does my description make sense? I'm not sure what this would be called but I've searched for a solution over the last few days and haven't found exactly what I'm looking for. If anyone has any suggestions or observations to point me in the right direction they would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: _"Stack Overflow requires me to post code from JSFiddle"_ - Indeed it does, and for good reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking has nothing to do with 'chaining' or 'conditionals'.  all you're doing is that when you submit, you look at the value of each of the two selects, combine them, stick '.html' on the end, then continue on.

Since you said you're new to JS, here's a documented fiddle which uses jQuery (which will make your life much simpler).  http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/vPJ9B/

Revised HTML (I added ids for the two elements):

```
<select id="select1" style="float: left;">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
</select>
<select id="select2" style="float: left; margin-left: 20px;">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
// tell jquery to wait until the document has loaded
$(function () {

    // setup an event handler to respond to the submit event
    $('button').click(function (event) {

        //combine the two values
        alert($('#select1').val() + $('#select2').val() + '.html');

        // for the purposes of this demo, disable the actual submit
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the requirement and for providing an answer using jQuery, manishie. This is incredibly helpful!